# Markdown header #4 not supported on careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, markdown

In any of the textareas, try entering a markdown heading #4:

```
#### This is a heading 4
```

It renders correctly in the "live preview", but NOT on the site after your publish (/cv/view-public).

Answer (score 4):

Just noticed that this is [still happening](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/benduguid), and means that I can't add correct headings into my experience history:

[image: Preview showing H4 correctly rendered]

However when I save the page I get this:

[image: No H4 in saved page]

As you can see from the mark up the title is being rendered completely outside of the `<p>` tags.

Adding standard headers `===` or `---` doesn't really help as the section heads for each experience are `<h3>`'s.

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this is on it's way out now.